# Express.js websocket server crashes when I refresh my browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple Express.js app which starts a websocket server and then the front-end connects to this server. When I start both the back-end Express.js server and the front-end server, everything works fine and I can see the incoming messages from the back-end being logged in the front-end each second.

However, when I refresh my browser, the Express.js server crashes and logs this:

```
Error: WebSocket is not open: readyState 3 (CLOSED)
```

The Express.js code looks like this:

```js
    import * as WebSocket from 'ws';
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
    
    const connect = function () {
        const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
        wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
            ws.send(createMessage());
    
            setInterval(() => {
                ws.send(generateMsg());
            }, 1000);
    
            ws.on('error', (err) => {
                console.warn(`Client disconnected - reason: ${err}`);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    connect();
                }, 1000)
            })
        });
    }
    
    connect();
```

And in my front-end, I have this:

```js
private subject = webSocket("ws://localhost:8999");

connect() {
    this.subject.subscribe(
      (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
      },
      err => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.connect();
        }, 1000)
      },
      () => console.log('complete')
    );
  }

connect();
```

Any ideas why the reconnection between the front-end and the back-end doesn't work?